# Finding Thread Id Of Called Function C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

In C++3 (VS 2008):

I want to find thread id of a called function when the function is called. Also I want to see when the function called; its name, file and line.  My Example is here;

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>

void test(void *param)
{
    cout << "In thread function" << endl;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") function in " << __FILE__ << " (line: "     << __LINE__ << ") was called by thread id: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;
    Sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second
    cout << "Thread function ends" << endl;
    threadFinished = true;
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Starting thread" << endl;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") function in " << __FILE__ << "(line: " << __LINE__ << ") was called by thread id: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;
    _beginthread(test,0,NULL);
    while(!threadFinished)
    {
        Sleep(10);
    }
    cout << "Main ends" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is output:

```
Starting thread
(main) function in .\CatchThread.cpp (line: 36) was called by thread id: 8200
In thread function
(test) function in .\CatchThread.cpp (line: 26) was called by thread id: 8860
Thread function ends
Main ends
```

This works the way i want. I can put "cout <<..." line which contain GetCurrentThreadId() in every function, because there are only 2 functions here. But in my real product there are thousands function and it is impossible to put into every function to this "cout<<..."

I've been searching for two days about it and I've used a function whose name is _penter(). It seems useful, because it invoked before every called function. But I could not get from _penter(); thread id, function name, line and file info.

I want to ask two things:

1. How can I do this without insert "cout<<..." to every function?
2. If it is not possible how can I add "cout<<..." to my every function?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thank you...

Comment: I see three immediate options: 1 use a macro that you painstakingly put into each function. 2. Use a decorator pattern to wrap your functions. 3. Write your own preprocessing script that will insert the desired code.

Comment: [Here's a tracing solution I made some time ago](https://pileborg.se/2016/07/simple-function-call-tracing-in-c/). You can modify it as you see fit (for example to add the thread id to the output).

Comment: You are asking about your solution. But what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @AndyG I will try. Thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, I am looking.

Comment: @IInspectable It's clear, please read again.

Comment: @jannissary: The description of your proposed **solution** is clear. What's missing is a description of the **problem** you are trying to solve. As it stands, this is probably an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381).

Answer (score 0):

In C++11/14/17 it looks like this.

```
#include<thread>
void calledFunction(){

std::cout << \_\_func\_\_ << " called from thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

}
```